# Fast to way to find the expected value and variance of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

You choose randomly two distinct elements from the set $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.

We denote by $X$ the random variable that is equal to the product of the two previously chosen elements.

I have to find the PMF of $X$, $E[X]$ and $Var(X)$ and I did find them but using the classical method by applying the usual formulas it was very easy but also too long.

Do you guys know a shortcut or some tricks to solve this kind of exercise?

The results I've found:

$E[X] = -0.5$ and $Var(X) = 3.05$

Comment: Is it ok to sample the same number twice?

Comment: Your problem leads to a distribution symmetric around $0$ so I would expect $E(X) = 0$.

Comment: @mlc  It's not symmetric...you can get $-4$, out of ${-2,2}$, but you can not get $4$.

Comment: @mlc I don't quite get your question but for example you cannot choose this pair (-2,-2) all the two selected elements must be different

Comment: I'm not sure it's a whole lot faster, but you could, for example, write $20\times E[X]=\sum_{i\neq j} ij=\sum_i \left(i\sum_{j\neq i} j\right)=\sum_i -i^2$.  And, analogously, you could compute $E[X^2]$ and deduce the variance from that.

Comment: @callculus 

here's all the values that X could take on :
2, 2, 0, -2, -4, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2,-2, -1, 0, 0, 0,-4,-2, 2, 2

there are 8 0's, 4 (-2)'s, 4 2's, 2 (-4)'s, 2 (-1)'s

which means $E[X] = -2(4/20) + 2(4/20) - 2/10 - 8/20$

Comment: My suggestion was the same as lulu's: $\sum_{i \neq j} ij = \sum_{i,j} ij - \sum_i i^2 = -\sum_i i^2$. Then divide by $20$. The point is that the first term in the middle is zero because once you've allowed the elements to be the same, the first and second draw are now independent. This does save some effort; if you don't use combinatorial tricks, the naive approach takes 20 terms, while this one takes 5 terms.

Comment: @1.2.3 That´s an appropiate way to calclulate the expected value. The time to think about a real simplification is exending the time you would save by using a simplification.

Comment: Possible values: -4, -2, -1, 0, 2. Probabilities: .1, .2, .1, .4, .2. From a $5 \times 5$ table, ignoring principal, diagonal. I agree with your mean and variance.